# adding new c++/winrt blank page create xaml but doesn't create .h nor .cpp files

Tags: uwp-xaml, vsix, c++-winrt

I am new to C++/WinRT and I am trying to learn how to use frames and pages in VSIX. My first approximation is to follow the example from Microsoft to develop app with navigation.

[Implement navigation between two pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/navigate-between-two-pages)

But when I try to create the second page for my app (I following the instrucions of [Section 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/navigate-between-two-pages#2-add-basic-pages)) the assistant creates the xaml file, but the .h and .cpp files are not created.

Should I create those files manually? Is there any step that I am missing?

Microsoft documentation is really wide. If you have a tutorial (book or detailed) guide for beginners to develop C++/WinRT application, please link to it.

Thanks

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Versión 16.5.2
Extension C++/WinRT version 2.0.200316.3

Comment: When you tried to add a new page, do you choose the Blank Page(C++/WinRT) option? When I added this, it can create the .xaml, .id, .h and .cpp file well. Do you only create the xaml file without .idl, .h, .cpp? About the tutorial for C++/WinRT application, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt).

Comment: Yes, I do.  There are some related question in the Q&A section of the C++/WinRT page at marketplace.visualstudio.com. Maybe, anyone knows a workaround? How to manually create those files?

Thanks, for the answer and the link.

Comment: When I updated my visual studio 2019 to 16.5, I can reproduce this issue. But according to this [post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/959456/item-template-dependent-nesting-behavior-broken-in.html), it mentions this issue has been fixed internally and is being prepared for release. You can wait for its update.